# apt-get update fails

Tags: apt, php

I am running these commands to reinstall php5.6 and I getting this error:

add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

> W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following
>   signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
>   available: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E W: There is no public key
>   available for the following key IDs: 1397BC53640DB551 W: Failed to
>   fetch
>   http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 172.217.8.142 80]
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the following commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <PUBKEY>
```

where  is your missing public key for repository, e.g.

Execute the following commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <PUBKEY>
```

where PUBKEY is your missing public key for repository, e.g. 6494C6D6997C215E.

Then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

ALTERNATE METHOD:

```
sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  <PUBKEY>
sudo gpg -a --export <PUBKEY> | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: thanks, but still getting this message:  W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: navigate to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and use `ls` to find the files present. If there is any file, please open it and paste its contents here

Comment: Hi, I found this file:    google-chrome.list  which contains the following:                                                 ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main